# Is the sentence logical?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity, logic, sentence-meaning

> It had been sunny for a week when the storm broke out.

Is this sentence logically valid and sound?

If I think of it, it looks like it means **when** the storm broke out, it was sunny. There couldn't be stormy weather and sunny weather at the same moment, could it? 
It's like being both black and white at the same time.

So it would be natural to say "It had been (or was) sunny for a week before the storm broke out", wouldn't it?

Comment: I'd not feel too jarred on hearing 'when' here (though I'd find 'was sunny' incongruous then). 'When' can be less than absolutely precise ('He'd been reigning for thirty years when the war broke out' - not quite the same situation, admittedly). But I'd use 'Before the storm broke out, it had been sunny for a week'. Again, the 'it-can't-have-been-an-instantaneous-change' problem is glossed over.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Why would you find 'was sunny' incongruous here? Isn't it allowed in modern English to use Simple Past with the conjunction "before" when the sequence of events is clear?

Comment: I said I['d] find 'It had been sunny for a week when the storm broke out' unremarkable but 'It was sunny for a week when the storm broke out' jarring.

Comment: We'd normally say something like "It was sunny for a week *and then* the storm broke out." Note that logic is not the standard to apply to any language, let alone English. As noted linguist John McWhorter said, "No language makes perfect sense."

Comment: I find the sentence entirely grammatical, readily interpreted, and with little scope for misunderstanding.  As to its logical soundness and validity, well those are matters of logic and off-topic, aren't they ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark. Thanks. I now think you're right - it's a matter of logic.
The example of Edwin with "him reigning" looks fine to me and logical. But yeah, I'm still not sure about "when" in my example with weather.

Comment: *"There couldn't be stormy weather and sunny weather at the same moment"* - Well [there could be](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunshower), but that's not what that sentence means.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a question about logic rather than about language.

Answer (score 3):

It is fine.  At the point the storm broke out, it “had been” (past sense) sunny.  Thus, the sunny and storm did not occur at the same time.  It is the past perfect continuous tense.

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/past-perfect

Comment: Hmm. I had been Gandalf the Grey for a few thousand years when I became Gandalf the White. Makes sense.

Comment: Not entirely sure the reference, but it reads correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to construct a sentence such as this that makes sense without context.

Your re-phrase, for example, could be interpreted as meaning that there was a sunny week at some point, not necessarily the week immediately preceding, before the storm broke out.

Groucho says:

> I was on safari. And one night I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got them on I still don't know.

Maybe you could write it as so.

> It had been sunny for the whole week just before the storm broke out.

And then my dermatologist's receptionist will ask "at night too?"   English is a weird language.